# In Underscore how to use each on a nested json object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a json object

```
user = { name: "somename", personal : { age:"19",color:"dark"}}
_.each(user,function(value){ if(isNaN(value){console.log(value)} )
```

How to get to the nested object value.

Comment: You have a JavaScript object, not JSON. If you know that's your object structure, you'd just do `user.personal.age`

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can access a specific value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-access-a-specific-value)

Comment: I would like to keep it generalized..as well as I would like to know if in underscore if it is possible to loop through at the nested level

Comment: The documentation also explains which arguments are passed to the callback: http://underscorejs.org/#each.

Comment: I don't know if underscore has something specific, but you could easily create a recursive function, so whenever you find an object, it would just recursively call that function, passing the found object.

Comment: `function deep(obj) { _.each(obj, function(item) { if (item && typeof item === "object") deep(item); else console.log(item); }); }`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work. If you expect even more deeply nested objects, then create a recursive function. `_.isObject(val)` is the key here.

```
_.each( {name: "somename", personal : { age:"19",color:"dark"}}, function(val) {
    if (_.isObject(val)) {
       _.each(val, function(v) {
            console.log(v)
       }) 
    }
})
```